# Setting the "Expires" HTTP header for static content served from Nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I'm using nginx to server my static content, is there a way that I can set the expires headers for every file that meets a specific rule?  For example can I set the expires header for all files that have an extension of '.css'?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I prefer to do a more complete cache header, in addition to some more file extensions.  The '?' prefix is a 'non-capturing' mark, nginx won't create a $1. It helps to reduce unnecessary load.

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Comment: All my static files were not found after adding that.

Comment: @JackSpairow: I can't really explain why that happened, as It has always worked for me. Are you running Nginx missing the add_header providing module? This kind of thing really is limited in scope, you sure another deceleration is not a problem in combination?

Comment: Probably another block had definition for the static files with a `root` set, in that case you should add the directives to that block. (I know this is 2y late, but for future citizens)

Comment: I personally appreciate clarifications, especially for future searchers because they often show up long after the original post. +1 :P

Comment: using this totally messes up my wordpress website. css and images are not show. is there any other conflict somewhere?

Comment: Remember nginx matches by location only, so this is an extremely common problem.   Also file extension matches are always a source of problems, especially with PHP.  first make sure you have a root set, either globally or if not, set one in the location bracket.

Comment: how to apply it to proxified backend. which is served by: <code>proxy_pass http://app_servers;? </code>

Comment: This answer is wrong, and will lead to problems. Check @amurell answer below https://serverfault.com/a/571403

Comment: @Kuzeko, It's not wrong, it simply doesn't consider what the user's configurations already are, as a potential problem can lead far outside the question's answer.   

The real answer is simpler, don't apply configuration snippets without really knowing the rest of your configurations.  At bare minimum, your doing a trial and error, so expect possible error.

Comment: please add `root` directive here to make this answer comprehensive

Answer (score 23):

```
server {
    ...

    location ~* \.css$ {
       expires 30d;
    }
    ...
}
```

The [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive

The [`expires`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) directive

Answer (score 22):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on why the accepted answer would cause the files to no longer show up, but I figured it out and would like to help out!

Short version:

Make sure you have a root directory specified for your location block on images if you do not have a global one set!

Long version below:

---

First of all, my method of implementing this solution was really similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17253805/2100636), where you write the rule (as in the accepted answer):

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

into a file **img-cache.conf**

and then include that file into your `server {...}` directive.

My example of somesite.com in my sites-available folder:

```
 #Image Caching
 include /etc/nginx/conf/img-cache.conf;
```

That way you can add the image caching location block to multiple sites you might be running.

---

Second of all, I have a situation where my /var/www/ contains two folders that I allow as public_html - secure and training, so I have to make specific location blocks in my site's server directive singling out these folders.

As such, **I do not have a global root directory set**.

So when you make your image location blocks, **you may not be providing them with a root directory** from which to look for the images in!

My solution was then to:

```
location ~ ^/training.+\.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        root /var/www/;
        expires 7d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        try_files $uri 404;
}

location ~ ^/.+\.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        root /var/www/secure;
        expires 7d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        try_files $uri 404;
}
```

Comment: +1 for making this a reusable `.conf`. The appropriate folder in `nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)` seems to be `/etc/nginx/snippets/`.

Answer (score 10):

All the aforementioned solutions will deny the possibility to have different aliases for different paths. Also for the sake of having all your different cache expirations in one place you should use nginx map in the following way.

...

```
# Expires mappings
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     7d;
    ~image/                    max;
}

...

server {
   listen ...;

   expires $expires;
   location /assets/ {
      # It is now possible to serve some resources from different path
      alias /var/www/my_other_path/
   }

   # and have them all have same expirations
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
...
}
```

`Off` disables caching, `epoch` (for unix epoch) results in resource always being refetched, `max` sets the date to browser max value.

The ~image/ matches any image types.

More about nginx maps at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html.

Comment: Note that if `$sent_http_content_type` is `"text/css;charset=UTF-8"` the above expression will fail.

Comment: For convenience above map block could be included in a shared conf file, then included in all the site configs you have.

Answer (score 9):

You can also set the expires to maximum. Here is the directive I use for css and js.

```
# Set css and js to expire in a very long time
location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

Comment: I would use the root directive only in the server {} block, when using it in sub locations it leads to unexpected consequences. You don't need the break; either, as you're not in an if {} block

Comment: You are right. Forgot to clean this up. Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have one place that is home to all your static files, something like this will do...

```
 location /static {
            your/location/to/static/files/static;
            expires 30d;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
```

The accepted answer caused nginx to not find any of my static files. Not really sure why, but this is a simple alternative.

Comment: I voted for this one but make sure you add the `/static` folder (whatever you set in location) at the end of the alias (right after `.../files` in the example).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers on this page are extremely outdated and/or convoluted...

For starters, the `Expires` header is not a good option these days, nor is the `Pragma` header... ideally, you should disable both of these headers in your [Nginx configuration](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/modules/nginx/nginx-conf.txt).

```
more_clear_headers "Pragma Expires";
```

It's much cleaner to set a single `Cache-Control` header on your static assets location block:

```
location ~* \.(atom|bmp|bz2|css|doc|docx|eot|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|mid|midi|mp4|ogg|ogv|otf|png|ppt|rar|rss|rtf|svg|svgz|tar|tgz|ttc|ttf|wav|webp|woff|woff2|xls|zip)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=691200";
}
```

Remember that for Nginx, if you use the `expires` directive such as `expires max` this is NOT just setting an HTTP `Expires` header, it's also setting a `Cache-Control` header too, so it can get very messy rather quickly.

TLDR just use `Cache-Control` on your static files so that CDNs like Cloudflare can cache them at the edge and/or browsers can cache them for a while.

[And I recommend](https://serverfault.com/a/1109669/144798) NOT using any cache headers for your page/HTML content on dynamic sites like WordPress because it will only lead to conflicts and confusion... if you really want to, you can just use an `etag` for your pages, but I personally don't and think those make more sense when using aggressive output caches like Varnish or Litespeed's LS Cache.

The approaches above are what we use in [SlickStack](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/modules/nginx/sites/production.txt) and it works fantastic for performance and stability, while guarding against e.g. WordPress plugins (or people) messing with your settings.

Answer (score -1):

Step1: Configuring Cache-Control and Expires Headers:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Add the following above the `server` block:

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}
```

And this line within `server` block. `expires $expires;`

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Source: [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-browser-caching-with-nginx-s-header-module-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Generally, we frown upon linking to articles and not including the content here as well, as links have a tendency to change or expire.

Comment: @Unkwntech I cannot agree more, I just updated my answer :)

Comment: The map block is better added in a conf file, then included in site configs.

Comment: Good to know, I would appreciate it if you can edit my answer or show me how to do so