# Enable cache headers on Nginx

Tags: nginx, cache, gunicorn

I'm trying to make cache work on a Nginx which is a proxy for gunicorn or which serves directly static files.

I tried to add:

```
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        root /home/admin/kids/app/static;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
```

But when I do that the server stops working.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 500;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css
               text/comma-separated-values
               text/javascript application/x-javascript
               application/atom+xml;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        root /home/admin/kids/app/static;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Handle all locations
    location / {
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }
    location @proxy_to_app {
            # Pass the request to Gunicorn
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

            # Set some HTTP headers so that our app knows where the
            # request really came from
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

There was the same problem [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/23157/setting-expires-headers-for-static-content-served-from-nginx) but I don't understand the comment which helps out.

> Probably another block had definition for the static files with a root set, in that case you should add the directives to that block. (I know this is 2y late, but for future citizens) –  aularon

Thanks.

Comment: What is the line with `example.com`? That is not a valid configuration line. What exactly happens when "server stops working"? What are the relevant nginx `error.log` and `access.log` lines? And what is the complete nginx configuration?

Comment: Actually, after I add location..., the browser get the Welcome page of Nginx when I go to the url.

Comment: Try moving the `root` directive away from the `location` block, to the `server` level.